# Bison nonterminal useless in grammar

Tags: bison

When I compile the below grammar with `bison test.y`, it warns that the nonterminals "header_stms" and "forward" are useless. Why? They are used in the "program" rule. The nonterminal "stm" is not reported useless.

```
%%

program: /* empty */
    | stm
    | header_stms
    ;

header_stms: header_stms forward
    ;

/* forward proc declaration */
forward: "forward" TK_ID ";"
    ;

stm: TK_ID "+" TK_ID
    ;

%%
```

The rules that use those nonterminals are also deemed useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because stm doesn't have how to reduce to the program rule, try this:

```
%%

program: /* empty */
       | stm
       | header_stms
       ;

header_stms: /* empty */ 
           | forward
           | header_stms forward
           ;

/* forward proc declaration */
forward: "forward" TK_ID ";"
       ;

stm: /* empty */ 
   | TK_ID "+" TK_ID
   ;

%%
```

Also, I solved your reduce problem in the header_stms, through left recursion.

Comment: Thanks! All I needed to do was add the extra rule `header_stms: forward` to end the recursion.